# How to loop through files in a directory and output the contents of each file in a <div>

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loop code for each file in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155533/loop-code-for-each-file-in-a-directory)

I assumed that I can reach this with following code but i think i make someting wrong with this code  `include($file[$])`

```
<?php
$dir= opendir(".") or die ('Cannot open directory');
$div="<div class=\"left1\">\n";
echo "<div class=\"wrapper\">\n";
for( $i=0; $i<6; $i++){
    while(($file = readdir($dir)) != false){
    if(preg_match("/php$/", $file)){
    echo $div;
    include($file[$i]); // HERE ITS NOT WORKING AS I WANT
    echo "</div>\n";
    }
    }
}
echo "</div>\n";

?>
```

Comment: Did you try with include_once ?

Comment: Trying using `echo` instead of `include` to make sure $file[$i] is what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL i used after your comment but the conclusion is not smilar to my expectation but thx

Comment: @andrewsi ok i will keep it in my mind thx

Comment: What is the contents of the files? If it's just HTML content, you might be better off storing it in a database and using an edit page with a WYSIWYG editor to update the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$file` is a plain string at this point, not an array.  So instead of `include($file[$i])`, you merely need to `include($file)`.

```
while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false){
  if(preg_match("/php$/", $file)){
      echo $div;
      include($file);
      echo "</div>\n";
   }
}
```

The entire outer `for` loop appears to be unnecessary.

Comment: but i need 6 different php files to be included  in 6 div tags , in horizantal direction along to page, and the next 7. php file must be included again below in same way to different 6 er div groups, its the reason i used for loop, i think i should use foreach maybe thx

Comment: @HilmiSleymanTunahanDemirkay Does it do what you want it to with the `for` loop as you have it? If I understand and you want to include the same group of files 6 times, then you will need to close the directory handle via `closedir()` and reopen it with `opendir()` on each loop of your `for` loop.

Comment: No it does not do what i want with for, it s just to give it a try,  i think your recommadations brings me more near to my goal.

Answer (score 3):

readdir returns the actual filename as a string, so you're trying to access that filename as an array, which'll extract just one CHARACTER of that filename.

Try:

```
include($file);
```

instead. Beyond that, there's no need for opendir/readdir, you could just use [glob()](http://php.net/glob):

```
$phpfiles = glob('*.php');
foreach($phpfiles as $file) {
    include($file);
}
```

Comment: +1 for `glob()` being the best option here.

Comment: ok thanks i try to integrate this code to mine, it looks more sophisticated as mine