# how to embed html files in php code?

Tags: php, html

I have many html files and now i want to call each of the files one by one using some php code. but whenever i try to run the php code for calling those html files from the folder, it doesnot work.

```
    1.html view
    2.html view
    3.html view
```

So, 1,2 and 3 are the html files and now  by clicking view user should be directed to the link. How can i solve the problem for incorporating html files in php, so that the files will be displayed to user one by one with a view option. And whenever user will click view, user will get the html page viewed.

Note: i m using xampp server in windows7

Any suggestions will be appreciated...

Comment: Do you mean you want to display html-files from a specific directory? Or just include() them?

Comment: @jitheman i want to embed html file in php

Comment: ya want to include html file in php.

Comment: If an answer answer your question, mark it, if not, tell us why.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use the [include PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for each html file.

example:

```
<?php
// do php stuff

include('fileOne.html');
include('fileTwo.html');

?>
```

Comment: If the html files represent truly static content, you should use [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). If the html file happend to include PHP directives (like `<?`), include will try to interprent them as PHP code. `readfile` will just return the content to the browser.

Answer (score 29):

Small improvement to the accepted answer: you should prefer [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) over `include()` or `require()` for non-PHP files. This is because `include()` and `require()` will be processed as PHP code, so if they contain something that looks like PHP (like `<?`), they may generate errors. Or worse yet, a security vulnerability. (There is still potential security vulnerability if you are displaying user-provided HTML too, of course, but they at least won't be able to run code on your server.)

If the `.html` files actually contain PHP code, you should name them appropriately.

```
<?php
// do php stuff

readfile('fileOne.html');
readfile('fileTwo.html');

?>
```

Comment: I additionally needed to call `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` before and after the `readfile` call respectively to avoid corrupt output.

Answer (score 2):

Using [opendir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) and loop throught the files.

Example:

```
<?php

    $dir = "/tmp";
    $dh = opendir($dir);
    while(false !== ($filename = readdir($dh)))
    {
        echo $filename . ' <a href="' . $dir . '/' . $filename . '">view</a>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

see here [Loop code for each file in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155533/loop-code-for-each-file-in-a-directory)

to know how to loop the files in the folder, then just echo an A tag with a link

Comment: Thanks .... but the problem is when i try to run an html file in php, it doesn't work. So, i tried to open the html file separately using a web browser by typing the link http://localhost/3.html but then also it dint work out

Comment: u cannot even open the file by simply browsing to it ? is this what u are saying ?

Comment: ya when i try to open it using localhost, since i m using xampp server. it doesnot work

Comment: then it has nothing to do with your php code or whatever? you should setup your server to correctly serve your pages before asking how to make your page do what u want ...