# Get images one by one from directory

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-slider

in php i want to ask how to get images one by one from folder directory and display in the jquery slider i have tried this php code by it's not working as i want?

```
 <ul class="jcarousel-list">
 <li class="jcarousel-item">
 <?php 
 $directory = "data/uploads/topslider/";
 if (glob($directory . "*") != false)
 {
   $filecount = count(glob($directory . "*"));
 }
 else
 {
 } 
 $files_index = glob("data/uploads/"."top"."slider/*.*");
 for ($i=0; $i<$filecount; $i++)
 {
   $num2 = $files_index[$i];
 ?>
 <img src="<?php echo $num2;?>" width="50" height="50" alt="" /> <? 
 }?></li>
 </ul>
```

i want display like this:

**Image1 Imag2 Image3......and So On from single folder or directory**

Comment: Take a look at '
Loop code for each file in a directory' http://stackoverflow.com/a/6155564/1089331 and see if it may help your request.

Comment: Apart from any other issues, I expect the carousel needs each image in its own `<li>` tag, and you are not looping in the right place, so that is a main issue to fix.

Comment: Also, please expand on 'it's not working as i want'. Is the code returning any looped image html? And if so, is $num2 being set as expected from the PHP?

Comment: @WilliamIsted and raad thanks to all it's working now what i want i got it ... Kit Grose gave me working solution

Answer (score 2):

There are four main things to check:

1. Is your `$directory` path correct relative to your current working directory in PHP? You can determine your current working directory by doing a temporary `echo getcwd();`. It needs to return the parent directory of your "data" folder for your code to work.
2. Is the `data` folder accessible from the current page on the web? e.g. if you manually remove the page from the URL (say, `index.php`) and add `data/uploads/topslider/someimage.png` where `someimage.png` is an image you know exists in your `topslider` folder, does the image load properly in the browser? If not, you'll need to update the way you build the `src` attribute in your `img` tag(s).
3. You're only adding one `jcarousel-item` for all your images, which doesn't seem right to me. I'm guessing you're expected to add a list item for each image.
4. You don't need to call glob twice just to ascertain how many files you have to work with. Just do a `foreach` statement once:

   ```
   echo '<ul class="jcarousel-list">';
   foreach(glob($directory . '*') as $filename) {
       echo '<li class="jcarousel-item"><img src="'.$filename.'" width="50" height="50" alt="" /></li>';
   }
   echo '</ul>';
   ```

Comment: @FarhanDharsi: glad to hear it! Please remember to mark my answer as accepted if it fixed your issue!

Comment: thanks kit grose u teach me new script thank you very much my brother