# Looping pdf report production

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf

I have inherited a web-based reporting application that is html/php/mysql in design.  Each record is assigned a unique id like 537-09-0588.

Currently the system is designed to allow a user to print a single report at a time.  However, **I need to design something (preferably in php) that will loop through and print all the reports en masse so that a user doesn't have have to click on the pdf icon for each report.**

There are a hundreds of reports now so the "one at a time" approach could take hours.  I'm grateful for any pointers in the right direction from the stackoverflow community.

Comment: Where are you get stuck? Storing those reports, providing the data, ...

Comment: I haven't started writing the code yet.  I was hoping for some pointers to help me get started.

Comment: Have a look how it works now. Modify this code to your needs. If you encounter a problem, then ask. If your current code base isn't very bad then it should not be too difficult to get your desired result.

Comment: Loop through the directory of your pdf documents and print them. --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155533/loop-code-for-each-file-in-a-directory

Comment: VMai:  did you mean to post a snippet of sample code?  Thanks for getting back to me.  Very grateful.

Comment: Tasos:  I apologize for being unclear.  The pdf documents do not exist as stand-alone pdf files in a directory.  They are dynamically generated from data in a mysql database using php code to populate a "template" form as needed.  I am trying to write some code that will take the existing php code that generates one pdf file at a time and add some logic to it such that it will loop through all the records in en masse.  I hope that adds clarification and thank you very much for your assistance.