# how can i return the names of files in a directory using php

Tags: php

lets say I have a folder on a webhost that is called sebis_files and this folder contains some files, maybe pictures, docs...

I want to return the contents of this folder on a separate page, something like:

```
$row = get dir host/sebis_files*//everything

for ( $row !== 0){ //for every valid file
   echo $row . "<br/>"; //return name of file
}
```

Comment: see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155533/loop-code-for-each-file-in-a-directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the Files inside a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086105/get-the-files-inside-a-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`opendir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) and `readdir`. Here's a breakdown:

We use `__DIR__` to make the path relative to the directory of the current script, just to be safe:

```
$dir = __DIR__ . '/sebis_files';
```

Next we open the directory to read it's entries.
We call `readdir`, which will return a 'resource' object, or false if `$dir` is not a readable directory:

```
if ($dh = opendir($dir))
{
```

The directory is successfully opened.
We now call `readdir` on that directory. We use the return value of opendir, the mysterious 'resource' object, that will let PHP know what directory we are reading.

Every time we call `readdir` it will give us the next entry in the directory. When there are no more entries, `readdir` will return false:

```
      while ( ($entry = readdir($dh)) !== false)
      {
```

We have read a directory `$entry`: the name of a file or sub-directory inside `$dir`. So, it's not a full pathname. Let's print it's name, along with whether it is a directory or a file. We will use `is_file` and `is_dir`, but we will need to pass the full pathname (hence "$dir/$entry"):

```
          if ( is_dir( "$dir/$entry" ) )
              echo "Directory: $entry<br/>";
          else if ( is_file( "$dir/entry" ) )
              echo "File: $entry<br/>";
      }
```

we are done with the directory, let's close it to free the resource:

```
      closedir($dh);
 }
```

But what if `$dir` cannot be opened for reading? Let's print a warning:

```
 else
     echo "<div class='warning'>cannot open directory!</div>";
```

Comment: what will the $dh and $dir be defined as? $dh = opendir($dir) and $dir = "mydir"; ?

Comment: The `$dh` from `opendir` is a "directory handle" that you need to pass to `readdir` to say which open directory you are reading. It is similar to `$f = fopen(...)` and `fread( $f, ...)` where you open a file and read it's contents. Don't worry about `$dh`, that is set up properly already. And `$dir` is simply the directory you are wanting to read - you weren't clear on what it is, but you could start with `$dir = "sebis_files"`.

Comment: also i keep getting this error for filetype-- Warning: filetype(): Lstat failed for ... in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\host\return.php on line 44   -- line 44: echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "<br/>";

Comment: Ah yes, I copied that from the php page. You can safely remove that. It's probably because `$dir` doesn't end with a `/` so it creates a wrong filename (like `sebis_filesfile.ext` instead of `sebis_files/file.ext`). I removed it from the answer.

Comment: @Kenny also checking the returns of the variables why does opendir return Resource id #3

Comment: Click on the `opendir` link in the answer and read what it says under "Return Values".

Comment: @user3582842 I saw your edit proposal. I updated the answer to explain every step. I hope it is more clear now!

Answer (score 1):

you need is to see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

```
    <?php
$dir = "/tmp";
$dh  = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    $files[] = $filename;
}

sort($files);

print_r($files);

rsort($files);

print_r($files);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the [glob](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.glob.php) function :

```
$dir = "/your/dir/";

if(file_exists($dir))
{
    foreach (glob("$dir*") as $file) 
    {
        if(is_file($file))
        {
            echo basename($file) . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```